# Unable to navigate from registerBackButtonAction using location.path

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to custom navigate on click of Back button. The idea is to send user to home page where in app he presses hardware back button and when on home page exit the app.

The event works but the new view doesn't load and if the back button is pressed again the app exits

index.html:

```
<body ng-app="starter" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
</body>
```

JS:

```
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $http, $location, $ionicModal, $ionicPlatform, $rootScope) {
  // Register back button
  $ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function (event) {
    // Custom function
    event.preventDefault(); // Back button will DO NOTHING.
    var path = $location.path();
    if (path.indexOf('home') != -1) {
      navigator.app.exitApp();
      return;
    }
    $location.path('/app/home');
  }, 100);
})
```

I even tried with the same code from inside

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers'])
.run(function($location, $ionicPlatform, $rootScope) {}
```

Does anyone how to make it work?

Comment: Have you sorted it out?

Comment: No I changed the functionality

Answer (score 0):

use:
$state.go('app.home');

don't use location.path